# Letter of Recommendation for PhD application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, postdocs, recommendation-letter, assistant-professor

I am applying for Ph.D. in the United States. During my undergrad, I had worked with a postdoc in the research lab I was working. Presently, the postdoc student has joined an esteemed university as an assistant professor, but has not yet started any research there. Can I approach him for a Letter of Recommendation for my Ph.D. application? How would that affect my application?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably depend more on how well they know your work and can predict your future success than their actual career position at the moment. If you did good work with them it should work out. So, yes, ask them. Especially so if this was your only research experience.

You likely need three letters. If this is the one you think "weakest" then you are in good shape. It is good that they have moved beyond postdoc, which will add a bit to their credibility.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I approach him for a Letter of Recommendation for my Ph.D. application?

Yes. It seems a good idea. I would suggest that you at least reach out to him. Generally, a letter from an assistant professor at an esteemed university, who worked with you in the past, is a good idea.

> How would that affect my application?

That depends on how the postdoc writes the letter of recommendation for you.

Specifically, it depends on how the postdoc thinks of your past performance in that research lab, and how he perceives your ability to learn and do research independently as well as in a team environment.

Do you feel that he really appreciates your work and contribution with him in the past ? If yes, that is a very good starting point.